# Cannot connect to domain despite successful pings

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

Pings to my domain name work, but I can't connect via http. I've been trying various methods for a week now, but haven't come up with anything that worked. Any idea what's causing this?

/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
ServerName machinename.local

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName chipperapp.com
  DocumentRoot "/Users/myusername/appname/public"
  <Directory "/Users/myusername/appname/public">
    AllowOverride all 
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 chipperapp.com
```

I can access the app from my local machine, but not on any other. I've set up dynamic DNS.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a firewall running?

Comment: Thought that might be the problem, so I shut it off while testing—still no luck.

Comment: What happens when you connect to http://127.0.0.1:80/ and http://chipperapp.com:80/?  Apache is running, right?

Comment: Apache is running: httpd (pid 50205) already running. I get my Rails app when running this from my local computer, but it times out when I try to access it from any other.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the site from another computer on the same network? You may be having trouble because of NAT at your network edge.

Comment: I tried accessing the site from the same network and an outside network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placing an entry in your /etc/hosts will not cause other hosts in your network to know your computer as 'chipperapp.com', even with dynamic DNS.  Dynamic DNS typically associates your local hostname with a DNS name inside of your DNS servers zonefile.  That's likely not 'chipperapp.com'.  You would need to either add 'chipperapp.com' to the /etc/hosts of the systems you are trying to connect *from*, or to a DNS server that is authoritative for that zone.

Comment: I have added it to a DNS server. When I ping chipperapp.com, I get responses back from my computer's public IP—the DNS is working fine.

Comment: When you say public IP, do you mean the Internet side of your WAN device, or your LAN IP (like 192.168.x.y, 10.x.y.z, etc.)?

Comment: The internet side, not LAN (ie. 10.x.y.z)

Comment: It looks like your domain (on the Internet side) is pointing to `68.170.77.58`.  Are you expecting that I should be able to reach the site from here?  If so, what sort of device (firewalls, routers, etc.) connects your computers to your BelAir Internet connection?

Comment: Yes, I'd hoped that the IP address would be accessible. How I connect to the internet is a bit of a black-box for me, since I'm on an apartment-wide internet connection.

Comment: Well, that black-box would need re-configuration in order to allow inbound connections.  I think you're out of luck with regards to getting this site accessible from your home.

Comment: Alright, thanks for all your help. At least know I know the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a few days again with 2 websites I was trying to access from my webserver. The fix was adding alias and restarting apache. here's my vhost entry in httpd.conf ; hope this helps

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin server@server.com
   ServerName www.yourapp.com
   ServerAlias *.yourapp.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

Also make sure that the following is uncommented

> # Use name-based virtual hosting.
>
> NameVirtualHost *:80

Comment: Did you mean ".com.com"?

Comment: Obvious mistake...

Comment: sorry about that typo, fixed :)

Comment: Gave this a shot, still no luck.